# Update translation file using Boost library Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I am using the **Boost** library in my **C++** project.

I am including it in the **PRO** file like this:

```
win32: INCLUDEPATH += C:/boost_1_60_0
win32: LIBS += "-LC:/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib/"
```

But, when I run the following command on the terminal (cmd) to update my translation file:

```
lupdate MyProject.pro
```

It searchs for files in the Boost library path to update.

**Is this normal? What can I do to not search in the Boost library path?**

Now, I am commenting the Boost include lines when I need to run the lupdate command, but I don't want to do it every time I need to update my translation file.

Qt 5.3.2

Boost 1.6.0

Comment: I have the same issue! Did you found solution better then commenting boost every time?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't found another solution so far.

Comment: @DvoryankinEvgeny please take a look at the cbuchart answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a workaround in the bug report ([QTBUG-27936](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-27936)), involving the `TR_EXCLUDE` option in the .pro project. It is used to tell `lupdate` to exclude certain files. I tested with Qt 5.6 and 5.8 and it worked as expected. Here there is the extract of my .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /Users/user/libs/boost
TR_EXCLUDE += /Users/user/libs/boost/*
```

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**
This is the previous answer, which I couldn't confirm and it happens to be wrong. I'm letting it here so it's kept documented. There is a workaround in the bug report ([QTBUG-27936](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-27936)), which is to include all Boost libraries in the precompiled header, since `lupdate` doesn't look at it.

Comment: Thanks @cbuchart. Do you have any example of how can I use `PRECOMPILED_HEADER` with the statement `win32: INCLUDEPATH += C:/boost_1_60_0`?

Comment: Sorry, I tested it today and it doesn't solve the problem. I've update the answer with a working solution.

Comment: Thank you so much @cbuchart, it worked. In my case I use: `win32: TR_EXCLUDE += C:/boost_1_60_0/*`